# RabbitMQ connection factory not auto injecting or converting message to JSON

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, javabeans

Im setting up the connection factory for my rabbitmq application. Ive got the beans created in the config, however for some reason the ConnectionFactory that ive passed into the RabbitTemplate doesnt seem to be creating the bean automatically as it should.

the error its saying is `Could not autowire. No beans of 'ConnectionFactory' type found.`
However this bean should be created automatically. It works if i create a bean of ConnectionFactory manually, but struggling to understand why it doesnt work without it.

```
package com.example.redistorabbit;

import org.springframework.amqp.core.Binding;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.BindingBuilder;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.Queue;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.TopicExchange;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate;
import org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.Jackson2JsonMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@SpringBootApplication
public class RedisToRabbitApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(RedisToRabbitApplication.class, args);
}

public static final String TOPIC_EXCHANGE_NAME = "covid-exchange";
public static final String QUEUE_NAME = "cases-entity";

@Bean
Queue queue(){
    return new Queue(QUEUE_NAME,false);
}

@Bean
TopicExchange exchange(){
    return new TopicExchange(TOPIC_EXCHANGE_NAME);
}

@Bean
Binding binding(Queue queue, TopicExchange topicExchange){
    return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(topicExchange).with("#");
}

@Bean
public RabbitTemplate publishingRabbitTemplate(final ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    final RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
    rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(jsonConverter());
    rabbitTemplate.setChannelTransacted(true);
    return rabbitTemplate;
}

@Bean
public Jackson2JsonMessageConverter jsonConverter() {
    return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
}

}
```

another issue i seem to have is even though i have the Jackson2JsonMessageConverter when the lisetener received and prints the message it is showing as bytes instead of a json message:

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Receiver {

private final CasesRepository casesRepository;

private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Receiver.class);

@RabbitListener(queues = RedisToRabbitApplication.QUEUE_NAME)
public void consumeMessage(final Message message) {
    log.info("received: " + message.toString());
}
}
```

received: (Body:'[B@1b68f46c(byte[91])'

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried Injecting the Spring Object Mapper into the Jackson Message converter?

```
@Bean
public Jackson2JsonMessageConverter jsonConverter(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
    return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter(objectMapper);
}
```

Comment: hi, so it looks like when i change the parameter in the consumeMessage method to the object which is CovidCases instead of Message i'm able to save the data into the database and return the body instead of a byte. Out of interest what does passing the objectmapper into the jackson2jsonmethodconverter actually do that is different from the Jackson2JsonMessageConverter itself?

Comment: The issue im having is i want to be able to access the headers of the payload, but by passing the object into the method as a parameter im unable to do that. However with passing Message into the payload im able to get the headers but unable to get the object back, instead it returns a byte. Any ideas?

Comment: I would need a bit more context here. From what i am seeing you are using AMQP. You should consider looking into SpringCloudStream. This usually makes it much easier. Can you also share the implementation where you are having your problem? In regards to the object mapper i have no clue what the default is that Jackson2JsonMessageConverter is using. I just know it is different from the one that spring uses for its rest template/rest controllers by default. That is also easier with SpringCloudStream :)

Comment: https://github.com/Thawqir/rabbitmq-messages-to-mongodb
youll be able to see the entire impl on there, the issue is with the consumeMessage method in the Receiver class, its currently using the CovidCases object and then saving that object to a repository but i need it to use the Message object so i can retrieve headers back and use them for retries etc. But if i use the Message object then when i return the payload the Body is returned in bytes:
`(Body:'[B@1b68f46c(byte[91])'`
 instead of my CovidCase object and i cant save the bytes to the database

Comment: @Bean
    public Jackson2JsonMessageConverter jsonConverter() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter(mapper);
    }

looking at your Imports you are still not using the Object Mapper which spring has configured. Try injecting the Object Mapper via dependeny injection

Comment: So that is another odd issue, i tried passing it into the parameter but for some reason it wont auto inject the objectmapper, same thing with connectionfactory. Ive pushed the changes up with the objectmapper passed in the params. is import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper; the wrong one?
`Could not autowire. No beans of 'ObjectMapper' type found. `

Comment: No i stand corrected com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper is the correct Mapper. But spring autoconfigures one which is different I belive. Thats why accessing it using the dependency Injection is prefered.

Comment: how would i do that?

Comment: I am sorry but for me it has always worked the way I have shown in my answer. If you are getting an exception by depending on the object mapper maybe the problem lies here that there is no object mapper known to the spring context.

Comment: This was a life saver. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue is with the version of spring-boot-autoconfiguration dependency, i could see the bean in the version for 2.7.3, in the JacksonAutoConfiguration class, however Intellij was still saying no bean was found. I added the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.15.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

and both ConnectionFactory and ObjectMapper beans have been created automatically